# How to get the radChildwindow without scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am using the following Javascript to open the child window using radcontrols in ASP.Net

```
function OpenrcdPopup(SchNo) {
  var url = "frmPF_TrackerRecd.aspx?SchNo=" + SchNo;
  var oWnd = radopen(url, "RadWindow_rcd");
  return false;
}
```

I have specified the window width and height in radformdecorator...

```
<Telerik:RadFormDecorator ID="RadFormDecorator1" runat="server"
                          DecoratedControls="Default" />
    <Telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager2"
             ShowContentDuringLoad="false" VisibleStatusbar="false"
             ReloadOnShow="true" runat="server" Modal="true">

    <Windows>
        <Telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow_rcd" runat="server" Height="393px"
                           Width="690px" Behaviors="Maximize,Close"
                           NavigateUrl="frmPF_TrackerRecd.aspx">
        </Telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>
</Telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

Hhen I change the value of the height and width, Screen size is varying according to that. But Scrollbar is also shown in the child window. How can I get the childwindow without scrollbars using radopen?

Please help me..

Comment: remvoe `Height="393px" Width="690px"` from child window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the window sized to `Height="393px" Width="690px"` and also not have to auto-size the window based on content by setting the page's overflow value to hidden in the HTML Head section:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .hid { overflow: hidden; }
        </style>
```

If you want the scroll bars for the parent window but not the child window, you can dynamically apply the setting.  First, set the body to a server control with `<body id="Body1" runat="server">`. Then based on your `SchNo` value in the URL query string, set the CSS class server-side if the value is for the child window. For example, the child window's value is "theChild":

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request["SchNo"] != null && Request["SchNo"] == "theChild")
    {
        Body1.Attributes.Add("class", "hid");
    }
```

Comment: also, have a look at this for common problems with autosizing: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-troubleshooting-autosize-not-correct.html

Comment: oh, and you can call the client-side autoSize() method of the RadWindow when your page changes dimensions. You can see it in action in the dialog page in this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/dialogreturnvalue/defaultcs.aspx